# Three different distance values (degree points and distance between them in meters), which one should I use?

Tags: python, coordinates, gis, geospatial, distance

I'm implementing a script that (ideally) has a threshold of <1 meter. However, I have three different distances being pulled from these points that differ by multiple meters. I was wondering which I should go by.

From my understanding, geopy uses a model of some sort for a more accurate number whereas mpu assumes a sphere and uses a "haversine" formula. The other distance derived referred to as "delta" in the script is what was there previously and I'm not sure how to interpret that one in terms of comparing it to the other two. Is there one you would recommend I use? It is reading a random set of survey points, usually around the coast of US.

```
deg_to_m = 111139  
lon_scale = np.cos(np.deg2rad(new_coords[1]))
delta_x = lon_scale * deg_to_m * (old_coords[0] - new_coords[0])
delta_y = deg_to_m * (old_coords[1] - new_coords[1])
delta_dist = np.hypot(delta_x, delta_y)

print(f"delta distance from point {new_coords} and {old_coords}= {delta_dist}")
print(f"geopy distance from point {new_coords} and {old_coords} = {geopy.distance.geodesic((new_coords[1],new_coords[0]), (old_coords[1],old_coords[0]) ).m}")
print(f"mpu   distance from point {new_coords} and {old_coords} = {(mpu.haversine_distance((new_coords[1],new_coords[0]), (old_coords[1],old_coords[0])) )*1000}")
```

Sample Results

```
delta distance from point (-73.54103769993867, 40.967273802785186, 17.68) and (-73.55888019993945, 40.96432750278418, 18.35)= 1532.7166288425676
geopy distance from point (-73.54103769993867, 40.967273802785186, 17.68) and (-73.55888019993945, 40.96432750278418, 18.35) = 1537.1838851634725
mpu   distance from point (-73.54103769993867, 40.967273802785186, 17.68) and (-73.55888019993945, 40.96432750278418, 18.35) = 1533.5205811777234

delta distance from point (-73.54103769993867, 40.967273802785186, 17.68) and (-73.55625289993931, 40.96710510278517, 18.32)= 1276.9866000176955
geopy distance from point (-73.54103769993867, 40.967273802785186, 17.68) and (-73.55625289993931, 40.96710510278517, 18.32) = 1280.9052835621858
mpu   distance from point (-73.54103769993867, 40.967273802785186, 17.68) and (-73.55625289993931, 40.96710510278517, 18.32) = 1277.6308281008874
```

Comment: The question is better suited to the [Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks @paisanco. I'll repost there.